# How to use more than 1 command in a button but it should not run simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I just started using tkinter. Below is the code for something similar to who wants to be a millionaire. I want to use more than one function in some buttons but they shouldn't go off simultaneously, rather they should go in a sequence. And is there any way to use the define lifelines and use them.(50-50 and Audience poll)

```
from tkinter import*
import pygame
pygame.init()

window=Tk()
window.title('Py Quiz')
window.geometry()
window.config(bg='black')
#defining Frames
abc=Frame(window,bg='black')
abc.grid()
abc1=Frame(window,bg='black',bd=20,width=900,height=600)
abc1.grid(row=0,column=0)
abc2=Frame(window,bg='black',bd=20,width=452,height=600)
abc2.grid(row=0,column=1)
abc1a=Frame(abc1,bg='black',bd=20,width=900,height=200,padx=130)
abc1a.grid(row=0,column=0)
abc1b=Frame(abc1,bg='black',bd=20,width=900,height=200)
abc1b.grid(row=1,column=0)
abc1c=Frame(abc1,bg='black',bd=20,width=900,height=200)
abc1c.grid(row=2,column=0)
#function to change lifeline image
def change_50_50():
    canvas=Canvas(abc1a,bg='black',width=180,height=80)
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img=PhotoImage(file='50-50X.png')
    canvas.create_image(90,40,image=new_img)
    canvas.image=new_img

def change_Audi():
    canvas=Canvas(abc1a,bg='black',width=180,height=80)
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=1)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img=PhotoImage(file='AudiX.png')
    canvas.create_image(90,40,image=new_img)
    canvas.image=new_img

def center_logo1():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture1.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo2():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture2.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo3():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture3.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo4():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture4.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo5():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture5.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo6():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2, bg='black', width=430, height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture6.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo7():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture7.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo8():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture8.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo9():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture9.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo10():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture10.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo11():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture11.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo12():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture12.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo13():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture13.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo14():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture14.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img

def center_logo15():
    canvas = Canvas(abc2,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    canvas.delete('all')
    new_img = PhotoImage(file='Picture15.png')
    canvas.create_image(215, 300, image=new_img)
    canvas.image = new_img



centre_logo=PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
centre_but=Button(abc1b,image=centre_logo,bg='black',width=300,height=200)
centre_but.grid()

life_50=PhotoImage(file='50-50.png')
life_50_but=Button(abc1a,image=life_50,bg='black',width=180,height=80,command=change_50_50)
life_50_but.grid(row=0,column=0)

life_audi=PhotoImage(file='Audi.png')
life_audi_but=Button(abc1a,image=life_audi,bg='black',width=180,height=80,command=change_Audi)
life_audi_but.grid(row=0,column=1)

prize_panel=PhotoImage(file='Picture01.png')
prize_pan=Button(abc2,image=prize_panel,bg='black',width=430,height=600)
prize_pan.grid(row=0,column=0)

question_1_ctrl=StringVar()
question_2_ctrl=StringVar()
question_3_ctrl=StringVar()
question_4_ctrl=StringVar()
ans1=StringVar()
ans2=StringVar()
ans3=StringVar()
ans4=StringVar()
question_1_ctrl.set('ENGINEER’S DAY is celebrated on who’s birthday in India ?')
ans1.set('Sir M.Visveswaraya')
ans2.set('APJ Abdul Kalam')
ans3.set('Mahatma Gandhi')
ans4.set('Sarvapalli Radhakrishnan')
def Question2():
    question_1_ctrl.set('What is the other name of Hertzian wave ?')
    ans1.set('Sound waves')
    ans2.set('Radio waves')
    ans3.set('Light waves')
    ans4.set('Matter waves')
    center_logo1()

def Question3():
    question_1_ctrl.set('Is Python case sensitive when dealing with identifiers?')
    ans1.set('Yes')
    ans2.set('No')
    ans3.set('Machine Dependent')
    ans4.set('None of the above')
    center_logo2()

def Question4():
    question_1_ctrl.set('Which of the following cannot be a variable?')
    ans1.set('__inti__')
    ans2.set('in')
    ans3.set('on')
    ans4.set('it')
    center_logo3()

def Question5():
    question_1_ctrl.set('Which one of these is used for floor division?')
    ans1.set('/')
    ans2.set('//')
    ans3.set('%')
    ans4.set('None of the above')
    center_logo4()

question=Entry(abc1c,font=('Times',14,'bold'),bg='blue',fg='white',bd=5,width=44,justify=CENTER,textvariable=question_1_ctrl)
question.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,pady=4,padx=10)
quest_a=Label(abc1c,font=('Times',14,'bold'),text='A:',bg='blue',fg='white',bd=5,justify=CENTER)
quest_a.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W,pady=4,padx=10)
quest_b=Label(abc1c,font=('Times',14,'bold'),text='B:',bg='blue',fg='white',bd=5,justify=LEFT)
quest_b.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W,pady=4,padx=10)
quest_c=Label(abc1c,font=('Times',14,'bold'),text='C:',bg='blue',fg='white',bd=5,justify=LEFT)
quest_c.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W,pady=4,padx=10)
quest_d=Label(abc1c,font=('Times',14,'bold'),text='D:',bg='blue',fg='white',bd=5,justify=LEFT)
quest_d.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W,pady=4,padx=10)

question_1=Button(abc1c,font=('Times',14,'bold'),bg='blue',fg='white',bd=1,width=17,height=2,justify=CENTER,textvariable=ans1,command=lambda:[Question2(),Question4()])
question_1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=4)
question_2=Button(abc1c,font=('Times',14,'bold'),bg='blue',fg='white',bd=1,width=17,height=2,justify=CENTER,textvariable=ans2,command=lambda:[Question3(),Question5()])
question_2.grid(row=1,column=3,pady=4)
question_3=Button(abc1c,font=('Times',14,'bold'),bg='blue',fg='white',bd=1,width=17,height=2,justify=CENTER,textvariable=ans3,command=None)
question_3.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=4)
question_4=Button(abc1c,font=('Times',14,'bold'),bg='blue',fg='white',bd=1,width=17,height=2,justify=CENTER,textvariable=ans4,command=Question5)
question_4.grid(row=2,column=3,pady=4)


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run more than one command from a button by using the following syntax;

```
button = Button(command=lambda:(command1(), command2())).pack()
```

The lambda command would also allow you to pass parameters through to the function. Using this you could probably use less function that do the same thing, instead having one method that can handle each logo, depending on passed parameters.

Comment: Putting a lot of code in a lambda is not a very good solution. It is better to create a proper function. Complex lambdas are difficult to debug.